# Jenkins reports a test build as a success, even though there are failures caused by exceptions?

Tags: maven, build, jenkins, webdriver, testng

I have SeleniumWebdriver/TestNG/Maven/Java continuous integration tests that are being run every time after a deploy. Sometimes an element is missing from the user interface and the tests throw an exception (which is later caught in the code, because in the catch statement I turn off the browser), so the build is marked as a success.

The strange thing is, I had failures in tests caused by exceptions before as well, and the build was still considered a successfull one.

How can I configure my maven pom.xml file or the jenkins build in order for it to mark every test that has thrown an exception, a FAILURE?

EDIT: After getting robjohncox's responce, I now have another thing I need to do:

How exactly do I throw the error again?

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    quit(driver);
    sendMail();
}
```

Is it done this way?

```
    throw e;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem relates to the fact that you are catching the exception in the code. Because you are handling the exception, it doesn't propagate up to your test runner, and therefore the test runner isn't aware that an exception was thrown.

After catching the exception and turning off your browser, you should re-throw the exception and then the test failures should be reported by your testing framework. The code would look something like this:

```
public void myTestCase() {
    try {
        // Do the testing
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        // Turn off the browser
        throw ex
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. will try it and share the results.

Comment: Just add `throw e;` as the last line in your catch block (as shown in the example above) :)